# How to display when response is Content-Type: image/jpeg

Tags: html, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I am using following graph api to get the user profile image. Its successfully returning the image in response tab of network

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}/photo/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUPN%7D/photo/$value)
[image]

**Response Header** -
Content-Type: image/jpeg

But I am unable to display content of this response in my html page. I tried by passing this image to `<img/>` tag

1. src="RESPONSE"
2. src="data:image/jpeg;base64,RESPONSE"

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your second try `data:image/jpeg;base64...` it expects a base64 data. So you need to convert the received binary to base64 first. The browser provide a [btoa function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) to do that.

Here's a full example:

```
const imageBinary = // here the binary you got from the api request

// convert to Base64
var b64image = btoa(imageBinary);

// use it in your <img> tag
myImgTag.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64image ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,please try this in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and check if it contains a valid image , if you got image on graph explorer kindly share the code with us, there might be issue in the code not in the API.